# Reading from ifstream until file ends

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm writing simple console application in cpp but none of my approaches to write it were succesful. I'm trying to read row after row from ifstreamed file until the file ends.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void lowtempbin(string inpfile){
    ifstream wyciag(inpfile.c_str());
    string row_temp_bin;
    int i=0;
    while(getline(wyciag, row_temp_bin)){
    i++;
    cout<<i;
    }
}
int main(){
      lowtempbin("danesystemy.txt");
      return 0;
}
```

Why the program doesn't enter while loop, and if getline does load nothing, then whole function should return 0? And then code after `while` is executed (not inside). I'll add that I pass as the argument to `lowtempbin()`inside `main`, name of the file that is in the same directory as executable (in code:blocks /project/bin/Debug).  Also when I debug the application, while loop is never executed, as if getline returns negative value.
Code shoud cout all numbers, one for every row, but it just returns 0;

Comment: Post a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please. What is `c_get()`??

Comment: I've read somewhere that it's necessary for string to use it's method c_get() before loading it to ifstream?

Comment: Your code example [fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3bb03a530ae1d4a) and doesn't reproduce the problem you state. My best guess is that `danesystemy.txt` isn't accessible from your programs current working directory.

Comment: _"I've read somewhere that it's necessary for string to use it's method c_get()"_ You probably confuse that with the `c_str()` function.

Comment: Yes actually that was the issue even that I double checked the directory.

Comment: @user378298 "*I've read somewhere that it's necessary for string to use it's method c_cstr() before loading it to ifstream?*" - that is true only in older compilers. In C++11, a `std::string` constructor was added to `std::ifstream`

Answer (score 0):

The program compiles and produces the expected result when ran. 
Your problem seems to be one of the following:

1. The filename is incorrect.
2. The file is not in the same directory as the executable.
3. The file doesn't exist at all.